# Shared variable in SSRS resets on new page

Tags: xml, variables, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, shared

i created an SSRS report in SQL server data tools, then created custom code with shared variables so that it would not reset whenever the user would change pages, it works great in the data tools preview and all is working as intended. BUT when i transferred the report's XML to a project i'm working on in VS (asp, js) the shared variables don't work as it should, the variables kept on resetting back to its initial value on every page.

this is a sample of my custom code in the report

```
   Shared Dim Total As Integer = 0;

   Function SetTotal(Value as Integer)
        Total += Value
   End Function

   Function GetTotal()
        return Total
   End Function
```

is there something that i have done wrong?